# Keyboard behavior when using backspace

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, backspace

I'm in a new computer, with Windows 7, and I've noticed a different behavior in my backspace key.

It is acting like in mobile devices.

This is the symptom:
If the keyboard cursor is at the end of some text, eg:

```
  hello this is some text|
                         ^
                        cursor
```

And I quickly press-release ~4 times the backspace, this is:

```
 backspace, backspace, backspace, backspace
```

It assumes that I want to delete much more than 4 characters, and continues deleting until the start of the word or phrase (I don't know exactly the behavior, but I don't like it)

How is this behaviour set/unset in Windows 7?

And as I don't like this behavior, there is a bonus question: how do I unset this behavior in Android?

Comment: In what program is this hapenning in ?  I have never observed this behaviour on windows, only in specific programs. This most sounds like a software feature of added software, or added software/driver.  Other stuff: There are some options in Control Panel "Ease of Access Center" "make the keyboard easier to use" "filter keys" which might slow or stop it, and a testing location there.  Also in the Control Pannel\all control pannel items\Keyboard is adjustments and testing. If you have added features via a keyboard driver, it might show up there in one of the property sheets or tabs.

Comment: At first I thought like you, that it was a specific program issue, but then I noticed that this happends in every program (chrome, visual studio, ms word, notepad, etc.), I will take look at the "ease of access" center...

Comment: What is the computer brand/model and is it pre-installed, or is this a windows you installed? Are you using an on-screen keyboard?  Double clicking and tripple clicking have always been nice ways to select words or phrases of texts? (how that applys I donno)

Comment: I lied: is not a new computer, I just formatted and reinstalled all (windows 7, drivers, etc). Before this (with the previous windows 7) it worked fine, without this behavior. I think that knowing the "name" of this behavior would help a lot. For example everyone knows what "swipe" means in the Android world, so here there must be a name for this backspace behavior

Comment: it sounds almost like you're in insert mode or have sticky keys set up

Comment: sticky keys set up sounds more likely, how do I set up that in Windows 7?  (I don't think INSERT mode applies to this case)